# Problem on Expected Value (Probability)

Tags: probability

We are given a set $X = {x_1,...,x_n}$, where $x_i = 2^i$. A sample $S \subseteq X$ is drawn by selecting each $x_i$ independently with probability $p_i=\frac{1}{2}$. The expected value of the smallest number in sample S is:
(A) $\frac{1}{n}$
(B) $2$ 
(C) $\sqrt{n}$
(D) $n$

My approach:

$X = {2^1,2^2,...,2^n}$

Smallest number in sample space is $2$ and probability of $2$ being selected is $\frac{1}{2}$. So, I think answer should be $\frac{1}{2}$ but it's not in the option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that the smallest number in the sample is $2^n$ is $\frac{1}{2^n}$ (The $n-1$ numbers
 before $2^n$ must be non-selected and $2^n$ must be selected).

The expected value is $\sum_{i=1}^n x_ip_i$, where $p_i$ is the probability for the value $x_i$.

Since every product is $1$ and we have $n$ of them, the expected value is $n$.

So, answer $D$ is correct.

Comment: I'm little bit confused. In question it is asked "Expected value of the smallest number in sample S" and you are calculating the probability of the smallest sample.

Comment: The probability that the smallest number is $2^{n-1}$ is  still $\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ the $n-2$ numbers before$ 2^{n-1}$ must be non selected and that $2^{n-1}$ and $2^{n}$ could be selected to create the sample giving you the probability $\frac{1}{2^{n}}$. In which case the product is not going to be 1 always to get the final answer n.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: If $2^{n-1}$ is selected, $2^n$ is not the smallest number in the sample. I edited the answer.